# regex: non-greedy search of vocals before a text

Tags: javascript, regex

i am making a script that is able to conjugate verbs, that are recognized when a word is followed by the (verb) expression. As an example: "i start(verb) everything"; so then i started searching for the regex "(verb)" and replaced it by the corresponding "ing" or "ed", resulting succesfully in: "i started everything" or "i starting everything" (of course that this system is not perfect)
The problem now; is that if the root ends in vocal, that vocal should be removed: for bake(verb) the search should have included the last vocal; to have as result "baking", instead of "bakeing", so then i changed the regex into: "[aeiou]?(verb)" as [aeiou] matches any letter between brackets, and the ? sign makes it non-greedy. 
This regex worked fine in the http://regexr.com/, but in my javascript code, it stopped finding.

```
function replaceTense(replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp('[aeiou]?\(verb\)', 'gi'), replace);
}
```

Where the "replace" variable is the corresponding "ing" or "ed".

Answer (score 2):

`RegExp` needs double escaping so `\\(` instead of `\(`.

You can actually use:

```
function replaceTense(replace, str) {
  return str.replace(/[aeiou]?\(verb\)/gi, replace);
}
```

OR using `RegExp` object:

```
function replaceTense(replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp('[aeiou]?\\(verb\\)', 'gi'), replace);
}
```